# Ultralight 2.0 commands with parameters (polling mode)

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

I have found some troubles working with commands. According to the sintaxis of the protocol, a command can be executed using an updateContext operation to the Orion Context Broker, which now it is working perfect.

The doubt is, how do I give the command some parameters, as specified in the protocol?

```
<device name>@<command name>|<param name>=<value>|....
```

If I send the following REST request, it gives me a 400 Bad request, complaining about strange characters:

```
curl -X PUT \
  'http://MYIP:1026/v2/entities/1111/attrs/blink?type=Thing' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -H 'fiware-service: howtoservice' \
  -H 'fiware-servicepath: /howto' \
  -d '{
    "type": "command",
    "value": "blink=true|another_param=false"
}'
```

Where should I issue the params if it is not in the "value" key?

If I use the following request, it acts as expected:

```
curl -X PUT \
  'http://MYIP:1026/v2/entities/1111/attrs/blink?type=Thing' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -H 'fiware-service: howtoservice' \
  -H 'fiware-servicepath: /howto' \
  -d '{
    "type": "command",
    "value": "true"
}'
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things regarding this question. Both of them relate to a wrong documentation, I'm affraid.

**Firstly**, the documentation should say the general way of sending a command from the Agent to the UL device is:

```
<device name>@<command name>|<value>
```

`<value>` then can be as complex as your device needs. For instance, it can be as simple as sending a single value:

```
dev1@turn|left
```

I.e. we are telling our UL device to turn left a valve.

Or it can be a composed value like this one (just an example):

```
dev1@turn|direction:left,lapse:3
```

I.e. we are telling our UL device to turn left after a time lapse of 3 seconds. In this case, we are sending the `direction:left,lapse:3` string because our UL device knows how to decode that. You could be passing many other alternatives, ir depends on what your UL device is able to understand; just some examples:

```
dev1@turn|direction:left|lapse:3 --> value is direction:left|lapse:3
dev1@turn|direction|left|lapse|3 --> value is direction|left|lapse|3
dev1@turn|direction left lapse 3 --> value is direction left lapse 3
```

Having this in mind, in the documentation example we must assume the `<value>` sent is:

```
<param1 name>=<value>|<param1 name>=<value>|...
```

**Secondly**, the above documentation example for `<value>` cannot be used :) Among all the possible combinations, we decided to documentate one that is not accepted by Orion CB (our apologies for that). Why? Because `=` is a [forbidden](http://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/forbidden_characters/) character in Orion CB.

Since values given to the commands are specified through Orion CB "update context" operations, i.e. the attribute modeling the command must be updated in order the command is forwarded to the Agent (because the Agent is the context provider for the attribute), such value must be according to Orion CB specification.

Therefore, updating Orion CB with any of the above possibilities, i.e.:

```
direction:left|lapse:3
direction|left|lapse|3
direction left lapse 3
```

is perfectly valid. It is not the case of `direction=left|lapse=3` or any other string containing `=`.

**EDIT**: documentation at [IOTAgent repository regarding command syntax](https://github.com/telefonicaid/iotagent-ul/blob/master/docs/usermanual.md#commands-syntax) has been fixed.

Comment: Thanks a lot @frb, I was afraid that this was happening! I also implemented previously to your answer the same sintaxis that you proposed :)

Comment: Answerd has been edited to tell that IOTAgent repository documentation has been fixed.